# $A^{-}A$ and $AA^{-}$ are symmetric when $A^{-}$ is reflexive

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, transpose, generalized-inverse

I'm currently trying to solve the following statement regarding generalized inverse matrix $A^{-}$;

> If $A^{-}$ is reflexive, then $(A^{-}A)' = A^{-}A$ and $(AA^{-})' = AA^{-}$

To start with, $A^{-}$ is reflexive, so $A$ is a generalize inverse of $A^{-}$. That is,
$$A^{-} =A^{-}AA^{-}.$$

Then, I have to show $(A^{-}A)' =A'(A^{-})' = A^{-}A$, which seems unlcear.  Simply substituting $A^{-}$ with $A^{-}AA^{-}$ does not give any useful information.

Any hints or other different way with respect to this problem would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are trying to achieve, do you want to prove that $A^- = A^-AA^-$ implies $(A^-A)' = A^-A$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is formulated, the statement is false.

Consider for instance:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix},\hspace{3mm}
G = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
We then have $G = GAG$ (and, analogously, $A = AGA$). However:
$$
GA = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \neq (GA)'.
$$